# What is this Mini navigation?

Tags: javascript

I am looking way of developing this "mini web page navigation" (at bottom right corner of the image). Quite frankly, I have no idea of how to search for this kind of feature. I am almost sure I could build it from scratch, but I would like to have some inspirations.

Can someone tell me how to search about this feature?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's probably https://larsjung.de/pagemap/ and it's usually called minimap

You should try to read the source code of the website before asking the question.

Comment: Thank you. I took a look at the code implementation but it wasn't very readable as the classes looked like this.

`
<div class="sc-1oa7p3z-1 dAzBvp"></div>
`